# Error in importing Laravel 5.0 project in Aptana 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, aptana, aptana3

I have imported Laravel 5.0 in Aptana 3.0.

Initially it was throwing the syntax error due to default php5.3 that I updated to PHP 5.4 by creating the file 
"**PATH_TO_PROJECT/.settings/com.aptana.editor.php.prefs**" with the following content:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
phpVersion=php5.4
```

It worked perfectly.

But it is still throwing two syntax error in the phpunit/php-token-stream/tests/fixtures/issue30.php

```
    <?php
    class Foo
    {
        public function bar()
        {
           return Foo::CLASS; //error line 
        }
    }
 ?>
```

and second file is

vendor/danielstjules/stringy/tests/createTest.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../src/Create.php';

use function Stringy\create as s; //error line

    class CreateTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        public function testCreate()
        {
            $stringy = s('foo bar', 'UTF-8');
            $this->assertInstanceOf('Stringy\Stringy', $stringy);
            $this->assertEquals('foo bar', (string) $stringy);
            $this->assertEquals('UTF-8', $stringy->getEncoding());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Any lead how to proceed further ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't you able to see what syntax error you're getting? Anyways, the top example are missing a semicolon ";", and the bottom example, is probably because you don't have "Stringy" namespace available...

Comment: sorry I missed the ";" but it still throw the error, let me check with the secone one

Comment: The src/create.php already has the namespace Stringy; included

Comment: atjoshi, you must be able to see what error message you are getting. Is it from PHP, or are you talking about an inspection error in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error myself. I was accidentally checking my entire project folder - including the vendor files - when I ran PHPUnit. The "use function" syntax isn't supported until PHP 5.6, which is your problem.

When I switched to debugging my app folder, which only contains files that I'VE written, the debugger ran without any problems.

Hope this helps!